# millis() vs creating a "long" variable

Tags: arduino-ide, millis

I think my issue is not fully understanding how the `millis()` function works;

I am wondering the difference between simply creating a variable such as

```
long fake_millis  ++ ;
```

vs using `millis()`?

Comment: millis() returns an unsigned long, not a long. It is never negative.

Comment: Besides the `unsigned` issue, how would you manage to do `fake_millis++;` exactly once per millisecond? Think about it: it's not so simple, especially if the program is busy doing other stuff. Best solution would be to do it from a timer interrupt. Once you do that, you have essentially reimplemented `millis()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`millis()` returns the **ACTUAL** time milliseconds since the start of the program. Wheter you put a delay, you do multiple tasks, `millis()` will still return the right time.

The other method that you mentionned will not work if, for example, you add a delay in the program. Then, for more complex tasks that might take more time, your "custom" counter will be very unacurate.

I short, just use `millis()`. It is easy to use and works great.

P.S. Use an `unsigned long` instead of a `long`.

Comment: appreciate the response.  I am wondering though for this basic formula where i just need to have a "second" counter, http://pastebin.com/raw/hxcVukR7    could  i just replace Millis() with my method ?

Comment: @danieljay, for that simple example, maybe, but for more complex programs, stick with `millis()`